# Date compare in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm doing app that read sms from inbox and if there are new sms's, upload them to FTP server. I use date comparing no to upload all sms's but only these that came since last uploading. To keep last upload date I use *SharedPreferences*.

This is code of my method which check if there are new sms's and if so, there are saving to arraylist.

```
public ArrayList<String> getSms() {
    sms_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    sms_uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(sms_uri, null, null, null, null);
    String sms_text = "";
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Date now_date = getDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
        if (now_date.after(last_sms_date)) {
            sms_text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")) + "#" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")) + "#" + now_date;
            sms_list.add(sms_text);
       }
    }
    if(sms_list.size() != 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        last_sms_date = getDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
        saveDate(dateToString(last_sms_date));
    }
    return sms_list;
}
```

The problem is condition:
 `if (now_date.after(last_sms_date))`
because even if there aren't new sms's, this statment is *true* for sms with date same as `last_sms_date`, so this sms is added to arraylist

Comparing dates with `data1.after(data2)` method should return true only when data2 is later then data1, but in my case it isn't so. 
Where is the bug ? The same is when I use `compareTo()` method.

getDate()

```
 public static Date getDate(String milliSeconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis( Long.parseLong(milliSeconds));
    Date date;
    date = calendar.getTime();
    formatter.format(date);
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Sms with date = last_sms_date is also add to arraylist when new sms's came.

Comment: Prolly your getDate method is f*** up... My assumption is easy: you setting the return value to some default then you are trying to parse the string... Parsing fail quietly... And you get your  default (which prolly is current time)

Comment: `Date.after` cannot return true with equal date... so you are not getting correct information...

Comment: And why do you convert date milliseconds String to Date object? Isn't it easier to convert it to long like:
long date1 = Long.valueOf(milliseconds);
long date2 = Long.valueOf(milliseconds);

Then you can compare 2 dates with a simple date1 < date2 operator?

Comment: even easier with `cursor.getLong` ... even easier with right `getContentResolver().query` call (with WHERE: `"date > ?"` and parameter `new String[] { Long.toString(last_SMS_date_stored_as_Long) }`)

Comment: anyway getDate is a little f* up(to much not used code ... it could be simple `return new Date(Long.parseLong(milliSeconds));`) but not in the way that could affect your code to such behaviour ... problem is `last_sms_date` ... it is the time of the first element of the **unordered** cursor ...

Comment: Thanks for help ! Everything works properly now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Format to date:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 


String A = formatter.format(today);
Date B = formatter.parse(last_sms_date);


if (A.compareTo(B) == -1) { 
System.out.println("A<B"); 
} 
else{
System.out.println("A>B");
}
```